# Why does comparing to nan yield False (Python)?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, nan

Here, I have the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> q = np.nan
>>> q == np.nan
False
>>> q is np.nan
True
>>> q in (np.nan, )
True
```

So, the question is: why nan is not equal to nan, but is nan? 
(UNIQUE) And why 'in' returns True?
I don't seem to be able to trace down the implementation of nan.  It leads me to C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\umath.pyd (row NAN = nan), but from there there is no traceable way to find out what nan actually is.

Comment: There are many things that are "not a number", ships, dinosaurs, cookies...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)

Comment: `NaN` in numpy at least has the property that `np.nan != np.nan`

Comment: Yes, I see, they are not equal. But you are missing three important points of the question:
1) Why (q is np.nan) is True
2) Why exactly (q in (np.nan, )) works
3) How is nan implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The creators of `numpy` decided that it made most sense that most comparisons to `nan`, including `==`, should yield `False`. You can do this in Python by defining a `__eq__(self, other)` method for your object. This behaviour was chosen simply because it is the most useful, for various purposes. After all, the fact that one entry has a missing value, and another entry also has a missing value, does not imply that those two entries are equal. It just implies that you *don't know* whether they are equal or not, and it's therefore best not to treat them as if they are (e.g. when you join two tables together by pairing up corresponding rows).

`is` on the other hand is a Python keyword which cannot be overwritten by `numpy`. It tests whether two objects are the same thing. `nan` is the same object as `nan`. This is also useful behaviour to have anyway, because often you will want to e.g. get rid of all entries which don't have a value, which you can achieve with `is not nan`.

`nan in (nan,)` returns True because as you probably know, `(nan,)` is a tuple with only one element, `nan`, and when Python checks if an object is `in` a tuple, it is checking whether that object `is` `or` `==` any object in the tuple.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. But it's kinda missing these two points in question:
 1) Why exactly (q in (np.nan, )) works?
1) How is nan implemented?

Comment: I did answer how it's implemented; it has an `__eq__` method which returns `False`. As to why `q in (nan,)` works -- basically because `in` checks whether an object `is` any object in the tuple. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I meant. don't you know where do I find actual implementation of nan in the actual numpy library. I do want to read it.

Comment: Typo: you write "in on the other hand" when you mean  "is".  More importantly: "and when Python checks if an object is in a tuple, it is checking whether that object `is` any object in the tuple" isn't true -- it checks if the object `is` *or* `==` any object in the tuple.

Comment: I'd make the slight correction that ``nan`` isn't a missing value, that is represented by ``na``.

Comment: @AntonBohdanov Sorry, I don't know that. You'll have to track it down yourself if you're very keen. I feel like I've answered your original questions though.

Comment: @JamesElderfield I'm not super familiar with `numpy` but `numpy.na` doesn't seem to be a thing?

Comment: @Denziloe Good catch, it's numpy.NA. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/neps/missing-data.html for its use and comparison with ``nan``.

Comment: I actually checked that and I have no `numpy.NA` either -- perhaps it's deprecated?

Comment: @Denziloe Aha no I need to read better - the linked document is an enhancement proposal rather than documentation of an existing feature

Comment: @Denziloe Rather, it's better to say that the authors of the IEEE-754 floating point standard decided that it was better to have `NaN == NaN` be false. numpy (and Python) just expose the C compiler's IEEE-754 floating point semantics.