# Deleting tuples in a list of tuples if tuple contains np.nan

Tags: list, numpy, filter

Filter list of tuples.
I tried a few things but the didn't work:

```py
    import numpy as np
    import sys
    import math
    #Python Version:  3.8.1 
    ZL = [('2011',np.nan),('2012',np.nan),('2013','B'),('2014','C')]
    #~ Desired output:   [('2013',20),('2014',34)]
    # I tried the following:
    #~ cleanedZL = filter(lambda x:x[1] != np.nan,ZL)   # Does not work
    #~ cleanedZL = filter(lambda x:x[1] != 'nan',ZL)         # Does not work
    #~ cleanedZL = [i for i in ZL if not math.isnan(i[1])]   # Does not work 
    #~ cleanedZL = [i for i in ZL if i[1] != np.nan]      # Does not work 
    cleanedZL = [i for i in ZL if i[1] != 'nan']      # Does not work 
    for a in cleanedZL:
       print (a)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is comparing to nan yields False (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856485/why-is-comparing-to-nan-yields-false-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your If statement then it will work.

```
import numpy as np

ZL = [('2011', np.nan), ('2012', np.nan), ('2013', 'B'), ('2014', 'C')]
final = [i for i in ZL if np.nan not in i]
print(final)
```

Answer :-

```
[('2013', 'B'), ('2014', 'C')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tries are all close, but your condition is not quite right.

Your main problem is that `np.nan != np.nan`, so you need another condition for testing. You could for example use `np.isnan()`, but this will fail if you feed in strings.

What kind of different values are on the second position of your tuples?
If there are only either `strings` or `np.nan` you could use `isinstance(x, str)` for your filter:

```
cleanedZL = [x for x in ZL if isinstance(i[1], str)]
cleanedZL = list(filter(lambda x:isinstance(x[1],str), ZL))
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710328/comparing-numpy-arrays-containing-nan) for maybe a better solution to comparing `np.nans`