# Unreliable mylist.count(nan) and no warning

Tags: python, list, count, nan

I have a list of values. Some of the values are corrupt and represented as 'nan'.
After manipulating some of the data, the 'nan' propagates, as expected and intended.

In the manipulated dataset, I want to find the number of useless values. Intuitively, I use the method `.count(nan)`, but to my surprise, and without warning, only the 'unmanipulated' nans are counted.

I found no immediate answer in
[docs.python math.nan](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=math%20nan#math.nan)
and the documentation of the [list.count(x) method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=lists#more-on-lists) is not very precise:

> Return the number of times x appears in the list.

```
from math import nan, isnan

list1 = [nan]

myitem1 = list1[0]
myitem2 = list1[0] + 1 # common operation: extract a value from a list
print(myitem2) # nan: looks like nan
print(isnan(myitem2)) # True: is nan

list2 = [1, nan, myitem1, myitem2]
count1 = list2.count(nan)
count2 = sum(isnan(e) for e in list2)
print(count1, count2)  # 2, 3: doesn't always count as nan
```

Answer (score 0):

While `myitem2` has a NaN value, it is a different `float` instance than `math.nan`, because the `+` operator always returns a new object, even if it has the same value.

`list2.count(nan)` only returns the number of times `math.nan` is contained in the list.

It helps to look at the object IDs (example values, they are different each time you run the code):

```
>>> id(nan)
140305278866152
>>> id(myitem2)
140305278866176
>>> [id(x) for x in list2]
[9079008, 140305278866152, 140305278866152, 140305278866176]
#   1           nan              nan            myitem2
```

Now you might ask,

```
>>> a = 5.0
>>> b = a + 0
>>> list3 = [a, b]
>>> id(a)
140133123191696
>>> id(b)
140133123191504
>>> [id(x) for x in list3]
[140133123191696, 140133123191504]
>>> list3.count(a)
2
```

why does this not return 1, as `a` and `b` are two different *objects* with the same value?

The explanation is that `count` in fact first compares every list item to its argument by identity, but if it is different, it then compares it by *value*.

I didn't find where this is specified, but here is the CPython [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c) (comments added by me):

```c
static PyObject *
list_count(PyListObject *self, PyObject *value)
{
    Py_ssize_t count = 0;
    Py_ssize_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < Py_SIZE(self); i++) {
        PyObject *obj = self->ob_item[i];
        // comparison by identity
        if (obj == value) {
           count++;
           continue;
        }
        Py_INCREF(obj);
        // comparison by value
        int cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(obj, value, Py_EQ);
        Py_DECREF(obj);
        if (cmp > 0)
            count++;
        else if (cmp < 0)
            return NULL;
    }
    return PyLong_FromSsize_t(count);
}
```

Finally, you need to know that comparing anything to NaN by *value* always returns "not equal", even if the other value is also NaN (I also didn't find where this is specified for Python, but see [Why does comparing to nan yield False (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856485/why-is-comparing-to-nan-yields-false-python) and [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)).

That's why `myitem2` is not included in `.count(nan)`, but `b` is included in `.count(a)`.